# Como configurar Bootstrap 4 com Angular 8.3.6 utilizando angular.json

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-8

Estou tentando configurar o Bootstrap 4 no Angular 8.3.6, estou seguindo os seguintes passos:

- `ng new novaAplicação` (criar o projeto)
- `npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save` (instalar bibliotecas)
- setar arquivos CSS e JS no angular.json nos arrays de style e script conforme abaixo:

  ```
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
  ],

  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
  ```
- Inserir componentes bootstrap para teste no app.component.html. No caso coloquei um alert.

  A simple primary alert—check it out!

Quando rodo o servidor (ng serve) aparece somente o texto, sem a formatação do estilo, quando uso um componente que tenha algum tipo de movimento (dropdowns por exemplo), este movimento também não funciona. É como se não estivesse reconhecendo os arquivos (css, js) setados no angular.json.

A alternativa parece ser colocar os links(css e js) do bootstrap diretos no index.html, ou, copiar os arquivos para a pasta assets, porém não vejo como boa prática visto o manual mostrar da forma que detalhei inicialmente.

Abaixo a configuração:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.6
@angular/cli                      8.3.6
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.6
@schematics/angular               8.3.6
@schematics/update                0.803.6
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Comment: Mas vc viu se dá algum erro no console do navegador, se deu qual erro foi? Não sei se percebeu mas o caminho do arquivo Js do bootstrap no **angular.json** está com uma extensão inválida!

Comment: Olá LeAndrade! Não há erros no console quando executo o servidor, nem no console do browser e nem no terminal. Corrigi aqui a extensão do arquivo, vou corrigir aqui no post, mas continua com o mesmo problema, parece que as informações dos arrays (scripts, styles) não migram ao rodar o servidor.

Comment: É José, em tese era pra funcionar, parece que está tudo configurado corretamente, só não posso afirmar 100% pq nunca trabalhei com Angular na versão 8, pode ser que tenha mudado alguma configuração pra utilizar Bootstrap, pq até a versão 7, o que vc fez já bastava para poder utilizar.

Comment: Encontrei alguns alguns posts no forum do Angular relatando este problema na versão8 mas foram encerrados sem terem sido tratados, vou reabrir lá.

Comment: Você tentou usar o scss? Eu fiz um projeto recentemente com ele, mas ao invés de colocar no angular.json, eu coloco um import no meu style.scss.

Comment: Sim, é possivel funcionar se linkar os arquivos js e css no index.html, ou no caso do css inserir um import no style.css. Porém é uma forma de contornar o problema, e não uma solução conforme a proposta da ferramenta, acho que se trata de um bug, reportei no forum do Angular, estão checando, tendo a solução, colocarei aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato adicionando no arquivo angular.json o bootstrap não carrega os estilos. Para resolver o problema, é necessário:

1. Adicione no seu index.html os scripts do bootstrap depois do app-root, dentro do body:

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

2. Importe o css do boostrap no seu arquivo styles.css:

   @import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Dessa forma, você aponta diretamente para o CSS do boostrap no seu index.html. Essa seria uma **solução de contorno** para funcionar o bootstrap com o Angular.

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo isso de forma paliativa. Valeu Giuliana.